# What is the use of join table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

For what purposes I'd potentially need to use join table?

For example, when I run `rails g migration CreateJoinTable products suppliers`, it creates the respective **products_suppliers** table with **products_id** and **suppliers_id** columns. Moreover, these fields have the option `:null` set to false by default. Why are those fields needed? What they are used for? And what is that null option?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To support `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's standard [`relational database`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) functionality.

--

Rails is designed on top of a relational database (typically MYSQL or PGSQL), which basically means that you're able to reference "associated" data through the use of [*foreign keys*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key):

[image]

> In context of relational databases, a foreign key is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that uniquely identifies a row of another table

---

In the case of Rails, "relationships" in the database are maintained by [`ActiveRecord`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) - an [*ORM* (Object Relational Mapper)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). This means that from the application layer, you just have to focus on populating objects:

```
@user = User.find x
@user.products #-> outputs records from "products" table with foreign key "user_id = x"
```

ActiveRecord manages your associations, which is why you have to define the `belongs_to` / `has_many` directives in your models etc.

Most associations you create will be reference other tables directly:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
end

#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

[image]

The problem with this is that it only allows you to associate single records; if you wanted to associate multiple (`many-to-many`), you need a [join table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

---

Rails uses `join tables` for [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) and [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) relationships...

[image]

Join tables are populated with (at least) the `primary key` & `foreign key` of a relationship. For example...

```
user_id | product_id
   1    |     3
   1    |     5
   2    |     3
```

This allows you to call:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

@user.products #-> all products from join table
@product.users #-> all users from join table
```

In short, if you want to have `has_many <-> has_many` associations, the join table is necessary to store all the references to the relative foreign keys.

Comment: The last diagram (assemblies/parts diagram) is what made it 'click' for me.